# c# stored procedure launch: Procedure or function expects parameter, which was not supplied

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_XNet_Backup]
    @backupPath NVARCHAR(4000) = null,
    @rc INT OUT
AS
BEGIN

    SET @rc = 0
    ...
    ...
```

Launched from c# project in this way:

```
SqlParameter[] paramters = new SqlParameter[2];
byte i = 0;

string sp = "dbo.sp_XNet_Backup";

using (SqlConnection conn = DBManager.CreateADOConnMaster())
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sp, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    paramters[i++] = new SqlParameter("@backupPath", completePath);
    paramters[i] = new SqlParameter("@rc", SqlDbType.Int);
    paramters[i].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

    foreach (SqlParameter param in paramters)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ...
    ...
```

But it gives me this error:

> Procedure or function 'sp_XNet_Backup' expects parameter '@rc', which
>   was not supplied.

Comment: If you're not assigning a value to `@rc`, then use `ParameterDirection.Output`

Comment: Side note, you should consider renaming your procedure and removing the sp_ prefix (or even better drop all prefixes). The sp_ prefix is reserved by MS and can cause some issues. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`, use `ParameterDirection.Output`

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@rc", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
try
{
    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
    }
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@rc"].Value);    
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
finally
{                
    cmd.Connection.Close();
    Response.Write(result); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening as there are no parameter values assigned before calling cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

please add values to and try, hope this helps

```
foreach (SqlParameter param in paramters)
   {
    param.Value = //somevalue
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
```